# Swift 5.3 is not showing in xcode 12 build settings

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am facing weird issue with xcode build setting for swift language version. I am trying to keep latest swift version i.e **5.3** but it is not showing in my xcode build setting. I upgraded xcode to 12.3 as well but no luck. Any suggestion?
[image]

Comment: this is the expected behaviour, in xcode 12.3 beta when you choose swift 5 it uses swift 5.3. Reference here: https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/ under Minimum requirements and supported SDKs

Comment: Is it? I feel Xcode 12.2 or mentioned version supports all three version. We can choose anyone of these. for example it says Swift 4,4.2 & 5.3, we are free to choose one from it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

XCode 12 comes with swift 5.3, we are not able to choose between 5.1, 5.2 & 5.3. If you want to use Swift 5.2 then you have to use XCode 11.4 as mentioned here: https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/

In order to determine which swift version you are using you can try this command in terminal:
`xcrun swift -version`

You will get something like that:

> Apple Swift version 5.3.2 (swiftlang-1200.0.45 clang-1200.0.32.28)

Note: If you have installed different versions of XCode use :
`xcrun --find swift` in order to find the path of each swift and then use the above command to determine it's version.